# How to merge two sorted lists?

Tags: python, list

I'm supposed to write a code to merge sorted lists, I got an error in the second function which says:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

my code is :

```
def merge(lst1, lst2):
    """ merging two ordered lists using
        the three pointer algorithm """
    n1 = len(lst1)
    n2 = len(lst2)
    lst3 = [0 for i in range(n1 + n2)]  # alocates a new list
    i = j = k = 0  # simultaneous assignment

    while (i < n1 and j < n2):
        if (lst1[i] <= lst2[j]):
            lst3[k] = lst1[i]
            i = i +1
        else:
            lst3[k] = lst2[j]
            j = j + 1
        k = k + 1  # incremented at each iteration
    lst3[k:] = lst1[i:] + lst2[j:]  # append remaining elements

def multi_merge_v3(lst_of_lsts):
     m = len(lst_of_lsts)
     merged = []
     for i in range(m):
          merged= merge((merged),(lst_of_lsts)[i])
     return(merged)
```

what does this error mean?

what should I fix in my code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **full** traceback, and the line that calls `multi_merge_v3()`

Comment: How do you call `multi_merge_v3` then? Because if you get an exception in that function, then `lst_of_lsts` is `None`.

Comment: Can't you just combine the lists, and sort them again? That would work if the lists aren't very big.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: tsk tsk, just ignoring the homework assignment? No, you'd use `heapq.merge()` instead!

Comment: You're not returning anything from function `merge()`, so by default it returns None that you assigned to `merged`. So, during the second call to `merge()` you'll be doing `len(None)`.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you don't need so many `()`, just: `merged= merge(merged,lst_of_lsts[i])`, you also don't need `()` around return, just simply `return merged`

Comment: Your "simultaneous assignment" isn't valid Python: i = j = k = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything from function `merge()`, so by default it returns None that you assigned to `merged`. So, during the second call to `merge()` you'll be doing `len(None)`.

```
 for i in range(m):
      #Assigning None here 
      merged = merge(merged, lst_of_lsts[i])
 return(merged)
```

So, at the end of that function:

```
return lst3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple take on the sorted-list merging problem.

```
l1 = [1,12,15,26,38]
l2 = [2,13,17,30,45,50]

# merged list
ml= [0]*(len(l1)+len(l2))


i1 = i2 = 0
for i in range(len(l1)+len(l2)): 
    if i1 == len(l1): 
        ml = ml[:i] + l2[i2:] 
        break
    if i2 == len(l2):
        ml = ml[:i] + l1[i1:]
        break       

    if l1[i1] < l2[i2]:
        ml[i] = l1[i1]
        i1 = i1 + 1
    else:
        ml[i] = l2[i2]
        i2 = i2 + 1 

print ml
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option: rely on Python's built-in `sorted` function:

```
merged = sorted(lst1 + lst2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer: use the "merge" function of [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html):

```
import heapq

merged = heapq.merge(lst1, lst2)
```

This is very efficient as merge expects `lst1` and `lst2` to already be sorted, so it only looks at the first element as it goes.

Note that `merge` also allow multiple (already sorted) arguments:

```
merged = heapq.merge(lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4)
```

At this point, `merged` is actually itself an iterator.  To get an actual list, instead use:

```
merged = list(heapq.merge(lst1, lst2))
```

Remember: with Python, the "batteries are included".